# Is there an option to rename a QUrl/shortcut in a SideBar of a QFileDialog?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I use the SideBar of a QFileDialog which gets it's QUrls from several folder strings.

I use the method fromLocalFile(dir) and it works great.
My problem is, those two paths have the same last folder name.
For example:

```py
place1 = "C:\publicDirectories\software\temp"
place2 = "D:\personalUserDirectories\software\temp"

dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self, 'search', directory, filter)
dialog.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DirectoryOnly)
dialog.setSidebarUrls([QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(place1), QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(place2)])
```

Qt takes the last folder name of the QUrl and name the shortcut like that. So when the dialog opens,  I have two entries called "temp".
Is there any chance to dig into the Qt code of the SideBar to rename the shortcuts although they still point to the same folders as shown above?
I mean something like you are doing to rename the Yes/No buttons of a QMessageBox...

I heaven't found anything about it in the qt documentation.

Comment: If you're using pyqt5, why are you using QtGui for QFileDialog, since it's in QtWidgets?

Comment: oh, ok, my bad. but this typo has no effect on my question. sorry.

Comment: No harm done, I only wanted to clarify that, since if you actually used QtGui it meant that you were still using Qt4, and the answer might change in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to set a delegate that changes the text displayed in the sidebar:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

UrlRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1
EnabledRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 2


class StyledItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    mapping = dict()

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        url = index.data(UrlRole)
        text = self.mapping.get(url)
        if isinstance(text, str):
            option.text = text
        is_enabled = index.data(EnabledRole)
        if is_enabled is not None and not is_enabled:
            option.state &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

places = {
    QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("/home/eyllanesc"): "Foo",
    QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("/home/eyllanesc/Pictures"): "Bar",
}

dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(
    caption="search",
    options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog,
    fileMode=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DirectoryOnly,
)
dialog.setSidebarUrls(places.keys())
sidebar = dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QListView, "sidebar")
delegate = StyledItemDelegate(sidebar)
delegate.mapping = places
sidebar.setItemDelegate(delegate)
dialog.exec_()
```

Comment: Note: the sidebar delegate also sets the enabled state for the option if the url is not accessible, so for consistency `initStyleOption` should also have `if index.data(EnabledRole) == False:` `option.state &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled`.

Comment: @musicamante I had not realized that the sidebar also had its own delegate by default

Comment: yeah, coincidentally, your UrlRole is exactly the same they use in the source code, so I wasn't really sure if you were aware of that or you just got lucky... it turns out it was just plain good, common *Qt sense* :-)

Comment: thanks, that is the solution to my problem! thank you very much.